# Object not found error when accessing roots sage theme css file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm new to wordpress. I try to install the roots sage-master theme as a starter theme for my wordpress site in my localhost.

But after i install the theme, the css styles are not working that the site looks without any styles.

when i try to access the css file by taking the source code, it says, Object not found error message. What should i do ? Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the necessary bower and npm dependencies and run the gulp build process? As [stated in the doc](https://github.com/roots/sage#install-gulp-and-bower)s. Specifically:

> #### Install gulp and Bower
>
> Building the theme requires node.js. We recommend you update to the
>   latest version of npm: `npm install -g npm@latest`.
>
> From the command line:
>
> 1. Install gulp and Bower globally with `npm install -g gulp bower`
> 2. Navigate to the theme directory, then run `npm install`
> 3. Run `bower install`
>
> You now have all the necessary dependencies to run the build
>   process.
>
> #### Available gulp commands
>
> `gulp` — Compile and optimize the files in your assets directory